# How to disable transitions in Plotly animations?

Tags: r, plotly

Using plotly for R, I can do:

```
library(plotly)
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, frame = 1:3) %>% 
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~frame)
```

which makes the point smoothly glide from one corner to another. But I want to make it behave more like a slideshow, so that there is no transition between the different frames. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all that's needed is adding `transition = 0`:

```
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, frame = 1:3) %>% 
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_markers(x = ~x, y = ~y, frame = ~frame) %>% 
  animation_opts(transition = 0)
```